# Sum of series with binomial

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, residue-calculus

How to calculate

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{2n}{2^{2n}(2n-1)}$$

?

I tried to use residues, generating function, combinatorics formulas, but unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}~x^n~=~\frac1{\sqrt{1-4x}}~.~$ Now ask yourself how you can employ differentiation

and integration so as to force an extra $~\dfrac{2n}{2n-1}~$ into the formula.

Comment: See [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) for more information.

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{2n}{n} \frac{2n}{2n-1}x^{2n-1}=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{y}\frac{d}{dy}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4y^2}}\right)dy$. If $x=\frac{1}{2}$ then we have $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{2n}{n} \frac{2n}{2n-1}\frac{1}{2^{2n}}=\infty$.

Comment: @mikis: Yes, $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}~\frac{2n}{2n-1}~x^n~=~\frac{4x}{\sqrt{1-4x}}~,~$ which indeed diverges for $x=\dfrac14~.$

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way for proving that your series is divergent. Since:
$$ \frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}=\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2n-1}{2n}\tag{1}$$
it follows that:
$$ (2n+1)\left(\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\right)^2 = \prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{4n^2}\right)\tag{2} $$
and since the product in the RHS of $(2)$ is convergent, we have that $\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}$ behaves like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ for large $n$s, so your series is divergent by the $p$-test. Anyway, a related convergent series is presented in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1164603/series-frac14-frac1-cdot-34-cdot-6-frac1-cdot-3-cdot-54-cdot-6-cd/1172188#1172188).